# jQuery div visibility toggle not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, visibility, slide

I have several divs for displaying demo boxes of graphics, and code boxes for displaying sample code for using the graphics. What I want to do is make the code boxes invisible until you click on the demo box - which should make the code box slide into view. ([See here to see how it looks](http://www.blastfromthepast.se/linuxbadges))

This should be super simple with jQuery, as I've done it several times before, but for some reason I can't seem to get it to work this time.

Here's a shortened version of my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
  //hide the all of the element with class code-*
  //$(".code-left").hide();
  //$(".code-right").hide();
-->
  //toggle the component with the respective class
  $(".demobox-dark").click(function()
  {
    $(this).next(".code-left").slideToggle(600);
  });
  $(".demobox-light").click(function()
  {
    $(this).next(".code-right").slideToggle(600);
  });
});
</script>

<div class="demobox-light">
    <div class="color_blacktext"> </div>
    <p>Black text</p>
</div>
<div class="demobox-dark">
    <div class="color_whitetext"> </div>
    <p>White text</p>
</div>
<p>Code:</p>
<div class="code-left">
    <p class="code">TEXT</p>
</div>
```

Can anyone spot the error? Cause I sure can't. Then again, I'm definitely no JavaScript wizard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have one "code-left" and one "code-right" on the page, Phill's answer will work great.

If you have more than one of these, and are catching the click on "demobox-dark", then trying to get the *next* "code-left", because you have a paragraph in between the two, it won't really be the *next*.

You could, instead use `nextAll` instead of `next` to do this? for example,

```
$(this).nextAll(".code-left:first").slideToggle(600);
```

Good luck!

Comment: ah yes, the `:first` would make my solution nicer and a lot like your ;) +1

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".demobox-dark").click(function()
  {
    $(".code-left").slideToggle(600);
  });
  $(".demobox-light").click(function()
  {
    $(".code-right").slideToggle(600);
  });
```

Comment: This will work in the sample, but on a real page (I assume) it would toggle everything that had class .code-left not just the one div.

Comment: And by "real page (I assume)" I mean a page with many blocks of code.

Answer (score 0):

When I use Firefox and execute some of your commands from Firebugs console `$(this).next(".code-left")` doesn't return any elements. I don't think this is very pretty, but you could try doing something along the lines of

```
next_code_block    = $(this).nextAll(".code-left")[0];
$(next_code_block).slideToggle(600);
```

Cheers.

EDIT: kept local variable by accident.

Answer (score 0):

[Funka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/110871/funka)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302418/jquery-div-visibility-toggle-not-working/1302477#1302477) works nicely.  I'd probably go with a more structured approach.  Assuming that each code block will only be associated with 1 demobox.  Each demobox, I'd give an ID (based on your demo page) -

```
$(".demobox").click(function()
{
    var $this = $(this);
    $("#" + $this.id() + "_code").slideToggle(600);
});

<div id="ubuntu_black_text" class="demobox demobox-dark">
</div>
<div id="ubuntu_white_text" class="demobox demobox-light">
</div>
<div id="ubuntu_black_text_code" class="code-left">
</div>
<div id="ubuntu_white_text_code" class="code-right">
</div>
```